# Command to add a blank line after each 30 rows in vim

Tags: original-vi

I have 51*249 rows in a data file and I want to add a blank space after every 249 rows in Vi editor. I tried to find such commands but failed to get one. Please help me with this one.

Comment: So, Vi or Vim? They are very different beasts. Also, you don't "find" a command, you *learn* your tool and apply what you learned.

Comment: I suggest to also extend your question with some examples, what you have and you want from it.

Comment: Another thing... is it every 30 lines or every 249 lines? Your title and your question's body seem to contradict each other.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Vim with `+eval`, you could do something like

```
:global/^/if line('.') % 249 is 0 | execute 'normal! o' | endif
```

You can use an external filter like `awk` by typing

```
:%!awk '1; NR \% 249 == 0 { print ""; }'
```

where the Awk program always prints the line (idiomatically `1;`) and then, every 249 lines, prints an extra blank line. (The modulo `%` has to be escaped in Vim, but not in a shell: for many commands, including `:!`, the `%` stands for the current file.)

A simple test case:

```
vim
:read !seq 1 20
:0delete
:%!awk '1; NR \% 5 == 0 { print ""; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

To go down 249 lines and add an empty line, you'd do `249jo`.

For a one-off solution, I'd actually record and repeat them using a recursive recording. Recordings are explained in `:help complex-repeat`.

To accommodate for the first span being only 248 lines, I'd add one extra line above with `O` and we're ready to start.

Just in case, let's clear register `a` with `qaq` (a shortcut that badly needs a catchy name).

Start recording `qa` and record the aforementioned command `249jo<Esc>`. Recursively call register `a` with `@a`. Stop recording with `q`. Or, in one line:

```
qa249jo<Esc>@aq
```

Now we're ready to run that thing with `@a`.

As a finishing touch, remove the temporary blank line we added above the content with `ggdd`.

Maybe not the most elegant way to do it but the first workable thing that came to my mind.